# MySQL JOINS use case

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

Lets say that I have a table **users** with the following fields:

```
id
username
email
hobbies
```

I have another table called **hobbies** that store specific information about each hobby:

```
name | unique
created
type
summary
```

Now normally someone would approach this problem by creating a many-to-many relationship and a join table, call it **user_hobby**:

```
user_id
hobby_name
```

What i'm trying to do differently is use the **hobbies** field under the user table that store a serialized array of hobby names.

So when I want to fetch a user's list of hobbies, instead of doing a join, I would do.

```
$array = $user->fetchHobbies()->toArray();
$hobbies = Hobbies::findByNames($array);
```

Performance-wise, which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance wise, its better to keep it in the normalized database structure, with correct indexes.

Reason being, if ever you want to say find all users that have a 'soccer' hobby you would either need to select every user and unserialize their hobby data, or run a wild card `like` match on the column, either way it will be slow for big data.

Comment: well that does make sense. My professor mentioned to me that on a large-scale application, relational database structure will break. Since then, my group has been trying to design a schema where such entities would be in one table.

Comment: When dealing with large scale applications there are many options, serializing data into a field is not one of them. You should however consider denormalization, clustering, high performance hardware, and/or document-oriented databases.